# Can't import an existing Key Store into Xamarin Archive Manager

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to add a Key Store to the Xamarin Archive Manager in Visual Studio, but I keep getting this error. The JAVA_OPTIONS is an environment variable I needed to increase the amount of memory used when importing Java projects into my Xamarin solution.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A new keystore should work here, but if it is an older/existing keystore, there are some known issues with the import tool which are currently under investigation. For the time being, please sign manually.

1. Manually Signing the APK https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/manually-signing-the-apk/
2. Xamarin forums discussion for “Can't Import Keystore” https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77998/cant-import-keystore